# Can not adding up numbers in a column with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im trying to get the sum of a column ("price") with angular with this code,  but only have the value.
Example:

Price: 5,7,8,9

Total Price:05789

```js
$scope.totalPrice = function(){
    var total = 0;
    for(count=0;count<$scope.names.length;count++){
        var product = $scope.names[count];
        total += (product.price);

    }
    return total;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `product.price` is `str`, so each time you use `+=`, you are concatenating the string.

Try using parseFloat or parseInt

```
$scope.totalPrice = function(){
        var total = 0;
        for(count=0;count<$scope.names.length;count++){
            var product = $scope.names[count];
            total += parseFloat(product.price);

        }
        return total;
         };
```

**EDIT 1:**: Double checking it, you declare `var total = 0` and that is a `Int`, the `+=` between a `Int` and a `str` should give a `Int`... weird stuff...

**EDIT 2**: Well, triple checking it... the first thing I said was ok :D `0 + "0"` gives `"00"`